# How to change font, background color on navbar & menus?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've found another SO question where it answers how to change the background color of a navbar, but how do I change the font, font size, etc of the navbar and sub-menus?

Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is probably to do it via Bootstrap's Customize page:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html

Alternatively you can just add CSS rules to your main.css file to overwrite the ones on bootstrap.css

Use Firebug to inspect the Navbar element and get the class names / styles etc and replace them with whatever styles you want to use.